# jQuery: redrawing function extremely slow when called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method called refreshHistory() that basically reads locally stored list of json (using https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) and populates a list in the order they were stored at.

Everytime a user action happens, this method is called. But as the list gets bigger and bigger, it slows down the browser to a crawl.

```
function refreshHistory() {
    var records = typeof store.get('history') == "undefined" ? 0 : store.get('history').history;
    ;
    if (records == 0) {
        $('#content #historyView').html('<i>history show up here in order.</i>');
    } else {
        var xhistory = '<div id="history">';
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var xaction = records[i]
            xhistory += '<div id="action">' + (i + 1) + '. ' + '<b>' + xaction.action + "</b> " + xaction.caption + '<span class="delaction" id=' + i + ' data-stamp="' + xaction.msg + '" style="color:red;cursor:pointer;">' + '[remove]' + '</span></div>'
        }
        xhistory += "</div>"

        $('#qtip-0-content #historyView').html(xhistory);

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) with a simplified version of your problem, that way others can give you more concrete feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering everything on every event is a simple strategy, which is good, but it does run into the performance problems you are describing. It's hard to give specific advice, but you could either:

- Implement a more detailed rendering logic, where only new items are rendered and added to the DOM.
- Use [ReactJs](http://facebook.github.io/react/) or [Virtual DOM](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) libraries, which allow your code to use the render everything pattern, but make the actual updates to the DOM faster by doing the minimum needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really make this efficient is to implement it in a different way.

I've been using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) personally and am very happy with it. Basically you write a template and the library handles the DOM node changes, only updating the parts needed. You will need to learn how to think slightly differently, but there are some great [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) available.

That said, one simple trick you can try is move the selectors outside the function so they are only ran once instead of each time you call the function.

For sanity I would also keep `records` variable the same type whether or not the `.get('history')` returns `undefined`.

```
var contentHistoryView = $('#content #historyView');
var qtipHistoryView = $('#qtip-0-content #historyView');
function refreshHistory() {
    var records = typeof store.get('history') == "undefined" ? [] : store.get('history').history;
    if (records.length) {
        contentHistoryView.html('<i>history show up here in order.</i>');
    } else {
        var xhistory = '<div id="history">';
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var xaction = records[i]
            xhistory += '<div id="action">' + (i + 1) + '. ' + '<b>' + xaction.action + "</b> " + xaction.caption + '<span class="delaction" id=' + i + ' data-stamp="' + xaction.msg + '" style="color:red;cursor:pointer;">' + '[remove]' + '</span></div>'
        }
        xhistory += "</div>"

        qtipHistoryView.html(xhistory);

    }
}
```

I doubt this will have a huge impact though, as I suspect most of the execution time is spent in the loop.